# Animate size of a UIView around center point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a UIView which I want to grow from it's center when a user touches it. The problem is that when animating it the view expands left and then moves to the right, whereas I want it to expand to the left and right, while keeping the center point the same.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(void) {
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 0, 320, view.frame.size.height)];
}];
```

I didn't think it was going to be difficult to do this, but it seems it is. Short of animating it manually with a timer I have no idea how to get it to expand from it's center.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not quite sure why it's working for you in a weird manner. Did you alter the `anchorPoint` property in any way? Otherwise it should grow from center.

Does doing

```
CGRect newFrame;
newFrame = CGRectInset(view.frame, -10, -30);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(void) {
    view.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

also give you the same result? What about this?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(void) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 1.1, 1.1);
}];
```

Comment: UIView doesn't have an anchorPoint property?

Comment: No but its backing `CALayer` does. If you see [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW1), it shows how altering the `anchorPoint` can have an effect on scaling.

Comment: Right thank you :) I knew I'd seen it somewhere. I tried using the first example and it worked how I expected, maybe it was because I was referencing it's frame inside the animation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code given by @Deepak Danduprolu and also don't forgot to UnCheck the "Use AutoLayout" checkbox in the show file inspector window of the storyboard.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just offset the X,Y position of the view. Lets say you're DECREASING both the width and height of the frame by 20 points: you should then ADD 10 points to both the X and Y position of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

instantiate the subview.center's to the parent's view.centerer, it solves the problem for me.

childView.center = view.center